# Regex to match and remove parameter in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have an url like **localhost:8001/?page=categories&catid=4&p=1888&country=1,2,3,6** and I want to remove &p=1888 part with regular expression. How can I match & exclude this part with asp.net c#?

**Edit:**
Here is the function I've created for solution:

```
public string RemoveUrlParameters(HttpContext Context, string[] Parameters)
{
    string result = String.Empty;

    UriBuilder urlBuilder = new UriBuilder(Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    var values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(urlBuilder.Query);

    for (int i = 0; i < Parameters.Length; i++)
        values.Remove(Parameters[i]);

    urlBuilder.Query = values.ToString();
    result = urlBuilder.ToString();
    result = Context.Server.UrlDecode(
    result.Replace("http://" + Context.Request.Url.Authority, String.Empty)
    .Replace(":80", String.Empty).Replace("default.aspx", String.Empty));

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I want to remove &p=1888 part with regular expression

I would recommend you to use url parsers, to avoid fragility of your code and guarantee that it will work for any valid url 100% of the cases because they respect the RFCs:

```
var url = "http://localhost:8001/?page=categories&catid=4&p=1888&country=1,2,3,6";
var urlBuilder = new UriBuilder(url);
var values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(urlBuilder.Query);
values.Remove("p");
urlBuilder.Query = values.ToString();
var newUrl = urlBuilder.ToString();
```

Implementing a valid URL parser with Regex could be quite challenging and not worth it especially when the .NET framework already provides you the tools to manipulate urls.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"&p=1888(?=&|$)", string.Empty)
```